# Scrapy Post request isn't working

Tags: python, post, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl this site : http://jadopado.com/

First I want to change the currency so I tried this:

```
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'cms_handler_name': 'jpintl%3Aon_setUserPreference',
                                          'country_code': 'AE'},
                                dont_click=True,
                                callback=self.parse_all_categories)
```

it's not working, I get the response with USD as the currency.
I even tried doing it using postman but it's not working
any help? you can check the http request when you change the currency from the upper bar of the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you just set the appropriate cookie `customer_country_code`, like this:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['jadopado.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url='http://jadopado.com/', cookies={'customer_country_code': 'AE'})

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        print hxs.select("//div[@class='country_code']/text()").extract()[0]
```

prints:

> AED

So, currency is set successfully.

Hope that helps.

Comment: worked :) thank you :) 
but do you have any idea why the other method didn't work ?